# Give up, give in

Tags: translation

Today I wanna ask you how to say "give up" and "give in" in german. I wrote some examples bellow.

1st example: The job was so demanding , that he was forced to ***give up*** on certain life aspects.

2nd example: This thing is so expensive! I have to ***give up*** on it.

3rd example: After all, he noticed that everyone in the room was right, and he ***gave in***.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1st: "Die Arbeit/Arbeitstelle hat so viel von ihm verlangt, dass er bestimmte Aspekte seines Lebens *vernachlässigen* musste." Of course, this refers to "neglect". *Aufgeben* would work, but not as well.

2nd: "Die Sache ist zu teuer, ich *gebe es dran*." This is informal, *aufgeben* does not work as well in this case either, but is possible.

3nd: "Am Ende fiel ihm auf, dass alle (Anderen) im Raum/(in der Besprechung?) recht hatte, und er *gab nach*." *Aufgeben* would be a stronger word, indicating more of a loss in this case.

Comment: "Drangeben" ist in Nordostdeutschland völlig unverständlich. Stattdessen sagt man hier "es vergessen" oder "es sich abschminken".